# How to make left and right divs sticky to the top on scroll at some point using JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In the following example I am able to stick the right div to the top on scrolling on a certain point but the same method is not working for left div and it spoils whole layout because I have to make the div fixed and when it becomes fixed it flows over the page!

[JSFiddle Here http://jsfiddle.net/xt9y7hqu/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/xt9y7hqu/2/)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank

```js
$(function() {
 var ele = "#rightPanel";
    $(window).scroll(
     function(){
      stick_right(ele);
     });
$( window ).resize(function() {
  stick_right(ele);
});
    stick_right(ele);
});

function stick_right(ele){
 $(ele).css("top", Math.max(0,($('#sticky-anchor').offset().top) - $(this).scrollTop()));
 $(ele).css("left", $('#centerPanel').position().left + $('#centerPanel').outerWidth());
}
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
  <h3>
    Navbar
  </h3>
</nav>
<div class='container' id='sticky-anchor'>
  <div class='col-xs-3' id='leftPanel' style='background: pink'>
    <h3>
    Sticky Left div
    </h3>
    <p> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xs-5' id='centerPanel' style='background: lightblue'>
    <h3>
      None Sticky center div
    </h3>
   <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xs-4' id='rightPanel' style='background: lightgreen; position: fixed'>
    <h3>
    Sticky Right div
    </h3>
    <p> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
<br><br><br>
```

Comment: Sorry, I have a hard time trying to understand what's your exact question.

Comment: @ZombieChowder if you run my code and you scroll down you will see that the right div sticks at some point to the top while I want to stick the left div also the same way.

Comment: Why someone down-voted my Question!!!!? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You go. Check out the [WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sq7q7mhh/36/) of your example.

```
 $(function() {
    var ele = "#rightPanel";
    $(window).scroll(
        function(){
        stick_right(ele);
            var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var panelTop = $('#leftPanel').offset().top;

        if(windowTop > panelTop){
           $('#leftPanel').offset({'top': windowTop });
        }else{
           $('#leftPanel').offset({'top':$('#rightPanel').offset().top});
        }

        });
      $( window ).resize(function() {
        stick_right(ele);
      });
    stick_right(ele);
});

function stick_right(ele){
    $(ele).css("top", Math.max(0,($('#sticky-anchor').offset().top) - $(this).scrollTop()));
    $(ele).css("left", $('#centerPanel').position().left + $('#centerPanel').outerWidth());
}
```

Comment: I want the left and right divs to stick to the top on the anchor point while you made both the divs fixed from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is nearer but when you scroll back from top the left div stuck at the same position.

Comment: @Muhammad Here you go. http://jsfiddle.net/gschambial/sq7q7mhh/35/ Also, Check the updated answer also.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great help.  I just updated your code a little bit so that it work even if someone resize the window. http://jsfiddle.net/sq7q7mhh/36/ update your answer I will mark your answer as accepted and up-vote you. :-)

Comment: @Muhammad Glad, I could help. I have update the code and link to fiddle as well in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't call the `stick_right` on the `left` panel.
2. You have the `position: fixed` on the right panel (but not on the left one).

I changed the code to work with the class `sticky-panel` (instead of the ID of the element, this way you can use multiple panels in one function call

```js
$(function() {
 var ele = ".stickey-panel";
    $(window).scroll(
     function(){
      stick_panel(ele);
     });
    stick_panel(ele);
});

function stick_panel(ele){
 $(ele).css("top", Math.max(0,($('#sticky-anchor').offset().top) - $(this).scrollTop()));
 $(ele).css("left", $('#centerPanel').position().left + $('#centerPanel').outerWidth());
}
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
  <h3>
    Navbar
  </h3>
</nav>
<div class='container' id='sticky-anchor'>
  <div class='col-xs-3 stickey-panel' id='leftPanel' style='background: pink; position: fixed;'>
    <h3>
    Sticky Left div
    </h3>
    <p> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xs-5' id='centerPanel' style='background: lightblue'>
    <h3>
      None Sticky center div
    </h3>
   <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class='col-xs-4 stickey-panel' id='rightPanel' style='background: lightgreen; position: fixed'>
    <h3>
    Sticky Right div
    </h3>
    <p> 
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this solution is not working as it makes both the divs only overlap each other.

Comment: btw, if you check your original snippet in full screen you will see that you have the same positioning problem with the right panel.

Comment: on full screen we have no scroller to refresh the position as I am calling the method on scroll but thats not the main problem, that can be fixed by calling the the method on resize the page.

Comment: Add `<br>`s at the bottom to see what happen in full screen (with scrolling).

Comment: I have added the `<br>` and now it comes to its own position when I scroll. let me add on an resize listener but thats not a problem

Comment: I just added the resize method so now it works on resizing the screen.